# Analyze API does not work for Elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

We are running Elasticsearch 1.7 (planning to upgrade very soon) and I am trying to use the Analyze API to understand what the different analyzers do, but the result presented from elasticsearch is not what I expect.

If I run the following query against our elasticsearch instance

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "stop", 
  "text": "Extremely good food! We had the happiest waiter and the crowd's always flowing!"
}
```

I will get this result

```
{
   "tokens": [
  {
     "token": "analyzer",
     "start_offset": 6,
     "end_offset": 14,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 1
  },
  {
     "token": "stop",
     "start_offset": 18,
     "end_offset": 22,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 2
  },
  {
     "token": "text",
     "start_offset": 30,
     "end_offset": 34,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 3
  },
  {
     "token": "extremely",
     "start_offset": 38,
     "end_offset": 47,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 4
  },
  {
     "token": "good",
     "start_offset": 48,
     "end_offset": 52,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 5
  },
  {
     "token": "food",
     "start_offset": 53,
     "end_offset": 57,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 6
  },
  {
     "token": "we",
     "start_offset": 59,
     "end_offset": 61,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 7
  },
  {
     "token": "had",
     "start_offset": 62,
     "end_offset": 65,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 8
  },
  {
     "token": "the",
     "start_offset": 66,
     "end_offset": 69,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 9
  },
  {
     "token": "happiest",
     "start_offset": 70,
     "end_offset": 78,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 10
  },
  {
     "token": "waiter",
     "start_offset": 79,
     "end_offset": 85,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 11
  },
  {
     "token": "and",
     "start_offset": 86,
     "end_offset": 89,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 12
  },
  {
     "token": "the",
     "start_offset": 90,
     "end_offset": 93,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 13
  },
  {
     "token": "crowd's",
     "start_offset": 94,
     "end_offset": 101,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 14
  },
  {
     "token": "always",
     "start_offset": 102,
     "end_offset": 108,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 15
  },
  {
     "token": "flowing",
     "start_offset": 109,
     "end_offset": 116,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 16
  }
   ]
}
```

which does not make sense to me. I am using the stop analyzer, why is the words "and" and "the" in the result? I have tried to change the stop analyzer to both whitespace and standard, but I get the exact same result as above. There is no difference between them. 
However, if I run the exact same query against an instance of Elasticsearch 5.x the result does no longer contain "and" and "the" and it seems much more as expected.

Is this because we are using 1.7 or is it something in our setup of Elasticsearch that is causing this issue?

**edit:**
I am using Sense plugin in chrome to do my queries, and the plugin does not support GET with a request body so it changes the request to a POST. Elastic Analyze API 1.7 does not seem to support POST requests :( If I change the query like this GET _analyze?analyzer=stop&text=THIS+is+a+test&pretty it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.x the syntax is different from [2.x and 5.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices-analyze.html). According to the 1.x [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-analyze.html), you should be using the `_analyze` API like this:

```
GET _analyze?analyzer=stop
{
  "text": "Extremely good food! We had the happiest waiter and the crowd's always flowing!"
}
```

Comment: I just figured out the problem my self. I am using Sense plugin in chrome to do my queries, and the plugin does not support GET with a request body so it changes the request to a POST. Elastic Analyze API 1.7 does not seem to support POST requests :( If I change the query like this GET _analyze?analyzer=stop&text=THIS+is+a+test&pretty it works

Comment: It's true what you say about Sense, and what I provided in my reply was tested in Sense. If I remove the `?analyzer=stop` part and put it inside the body, it will not work anymore, but the text will be analyzed, but not with `stop` analyzer.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand it now :) But still much neater in 2+

Comment: Yes, that's why ES is evolving :), to improve itself.